# How to get geo location in UC Browser For PC (Automatically) on Load of Page?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, uc-browser

I have set the geolocation on my page. Its working on fine on all browser except UC Browser.

Its working fine on UC Browser Mobile but not for PC Broswer.

Here is sample code for getting latitude and longitude on click. This is not working for UC Browser PC.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please Help me for this.

Comment: Some browsers are not allowing geolocation unless page is served https. Chrome for example: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only